# sorting function in python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of objects according to my criteria.

Here is my sorting function:

```
def sort_pots(self, pot1, pot2):
    coeff1 = ((pot1.movable + pot1.convertible) / pot1.total)
    coeff2 = ((pot2.movable + pot2.convertible) / pot2.total)

    if coeff1 > coeff2:
        return 1
    elif coeff1 == coeff2:
        return pot1.total - pot2.total
    else:
        return -1
```

What i would like to achieve is:
if coeff1 > coeff2, pot1 is before pot2
if coeff1 == coeff2, the one with the highest total is before
else (coeff2 > coeff1), pot2 is before pot2

and the function doesn't seem to work accordingly. I've got a bunch ordered according to total but not with same coeff.
I've (convertible, movable, total):  0, 0, 1 and later 0, 3, 4 and then 31, 228, 1584 and then 1, 0, 1

Here is the beginning of the definition of the class of pot1 and pot2:

```
class Potential:
    def __init__(self,conf_opt):
        self.conf_opt = conf_opt
        self.total = 0
        self.movable = 0
        self.convertible = 0
```

thanks.

Comment: I guess <code>return pot1.total - pot2.total</code> is a mistake as your function should returns only 1,0 or -1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
def coef(pot):
    return (pot.movable + pot.convertible) / float(pot.total)

l.sort(key=lambda x: (coef(x), x.total), reverse=True)
```

It should even be faster (key is better than cmp).

Comment: He wants to sort descending, so `reverse=True`.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a final note, you could override the `__cmp__` method as follows:

```
class Potential(object): # new style classes FTW!
    ...
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        coeff1 = (self.movable + self.convertible) / self.total
        coeff2 = (other.movable + other.convertible) / other.total
        return cmp((coeff1, self.total), (coeff2, other.total))
```

That way, the normal sorting order is achieved just by calling `sort()` with no arguments. You might even make the suggested `coeff` function a part of your class:

```
class Potential(object):
    ...
    def coeff(self):
        return (self.movable + self.convertible) / self.total

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp((self.coeff(), self.total), (other.coeff(), other.total))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think tonfa's answer is the most readable but if you want to do it with the code you have you should try:

```
def sort_pots(self, pot1, pot2):
    coeff1 = ((pot1.movable + pot1.convertible) / pot1.total)
    coeff2 = ((pot2.movable + pot2.convertible) / pot2.total)

    if coeff1 > coeff2:
        return 1
    elif coeff1 == coeff2:
        return cmp(pot1.total,pot2.total)
    else:
        return -1
```

Edit: Used [cmp](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#cmp) method rather than long form if/else

Comment: if you want to do that, just call `-cmp(pot1.total, pot2.total)`.

Comment: just returning 1 or -1 makes the difference ?